# HTML5 localStorage, how to exclude certain fields

Tags: jquery, html

Following this tutorial, http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/96-localstorage-for-forms/, I was able to make recreate the localStorage functionality with my form, however I would like it to exclude certain fields, such as credit card numbers.

Can I do it by somehow targeting the ID associated with the credit card input and not save it into localStorage?

Here's the save function,

```
  $("#saveData")
        .click(function(e) {


            e.preventDefault();


            localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");


            var data = $("#form1").serializeArray();


            $.each(data, function(i, obj) {

                localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);
            });             

        });
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to exclude based off the input name from the credit card element. This is the simplest answer but also the least reusable. Depending on what you are doing you may want to add flags for not saving into your html or setup a map of known input names that should never be saved, etc, for more reusability.

```
  $("#saveData")
    .click(function(e) {


        e.preventDefault();


        localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");


        var data = $("#form1").serializeArray();


        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            if(obj.name != "creditCard") {
                localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);
            }
        });             

    });
```